# Is this the right way to set font family for all headings and everything inside the headings?

Tags: css

I want all headings and everything in them, such as anchor tags, to be a certain font family. This works:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h1 > *, h2 > *, h3 > *, h4 > *, h5 > *, h6 > * {
 font-family: serif;
}
```

I was wondering if this is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Efficient how? Using the universal selector is generally a bad idea, and it won't help if a selector is more specific. For instance, adding the following rule after yours would override it: `h1 > span.super-important { font-family: sans-serif; }`...

Comment: First, for _everything_ (and not just direct descendants) you should use whitespace instead of `>`. And specificity of `h1 *` will still be lower than `a.something`, for example.

Answer (score 9):

font-family is inherited, so it you're not overriding it elsewhere, you can simply do this which will work for the child elements too:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family:serif;}
```

If you are overriding it elsewhere, then it depends how exactly you're overriding it to know what specificity you need here.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and that's what I thought should happen. I'm experimenting with bootstrap 4 and maybe it's strongarming the css or maybe it really wants me to adjust fonts via scss.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to apply it to all texts (paragraph or headers), you could use

`* {font-family: sans-serif}` in your CSS file

Comment: The answer is too short and doesn't provide the correct answer plus I think it should have been as a comment rather than an answer.